# Crash in MobileFirst 7.1-based app when using cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, android-fingerprint-api

i am using [cordova fingerprint auth plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth) in my application, but the application crashes and shows the below errors in logcat.

> 11-14 11:12:47.671: W/PluginManager(30565): THREAD WARNING: exec()
>   call to FingerprintAuth.authenticate blocked the main thread for 33ms.
>   Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
>
> 11-14 11:12:47.712: D/FingerprintAuthDialog(30565): disableBackup:
>   false 11-14 11:12:47.713: W/ResourceType(30565): No package identifier
>   when getting      value for resource number 0x00000000 11-14
>   11:12:47.713: D/AndroidRuntime(30565): Shutting down VM 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565): Process: com.fingerPrint, PID:
>   30565 11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2777)
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   com.fingerPrint.FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.onCreateView(FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java:87)
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1537)
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 11-14 11:12:47.716:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 11-14
>   11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-14 11:12:47.716:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>   11-14 11:12:47.716: E/AndroidRuntime(30565):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):
>   Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java:471
>   :: Uncaught Exception 11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2777)
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   com.fingerPrint.FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.onCreateView(FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java:87)
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1537)
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 11-14
>   11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>   11-14 11:12:47.718:
>   E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler(30565):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 11-14
>   11:12:47.723: D/com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLLifecycleHelper(30565):
>   WLLifecycleHelper.logAppSession in WLLifecycleHelper.java:109 :: Tried
>   to record an app crash without a starting timestamp

Steps Followed:

1. Added plugin **FingerprintAuth.java**, **FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment‌​.java**, **FingerprintUiHelper.java** files into **android/src/com/** folder
2. Added to **config.xml**

   ```
   <feature name="FingerprintAuth">
       <param name="android-package"  value="com.fingerPrint.FingerprintAuth"/>
   </feature>
   ```
3. Added **FingerprintAuth.js** in **common/js** folder
4. Every time add the following in **cordova_plugins.js** before deploying to device

   ```
   { "id": "FingerprintAuth", "file": "../js/FingerprintAuth.js", "clobbers": [ "FingerprintAuth" ] }
   ```

5.To check fingerprint authentication added below code in main.js file

```
FingerprintAuth.isAvailable(function(result) {
        if (result.isAvailable) {
              var client_id = "Your client ID";
              var client_secret = "A very secret client secret (once per device)";
                if(result.hasEnrolledFingerprints){
                        FingerprintAuth.show({
                                clientId: client_id,
                                clientSecret: client_secret
                        }, function (result) {
                                if (result.withFingerprint) {


                                            alert("Authentication Success");


                                             //$location.path("singin");

                                } else if (result.withPassword) {
                                        alert("Authenticated with backup password");
                                }
                        }, function(error) {
                                console.log(error); // "Fingerprint authentication not available"
                        });
                }else{
                        alert("Fingerprint auth available, but no fingerprint registered on the device");
                }
        }
}, function(message) {
        alert("Cannot detect fingerprint device : "+ message);
});
```

Comment: Is this a Cordova app created with the MobileFirst CLI 7.1, or a Hybrid app created in MobileFirst Studio 7.1?

Comment: Hybrid app created in MobileFirst Studio 7.1, just added cordova-plugin

Comment: How did you add the plug-in? Hybrid apps don't really support 3rd party cordova plug-ins.

Comment: Steps Followed
1.Added plugin FingerprintAuth.java,FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.java,
FingerprintUiHelper.java files into android src/com/<project name> folder
2.Added <feature name="FingerprintAuth">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.fingerPrint.FingerprintAuth"/></feature> into config.xml
3.Added FingerprintAuth.js into common/js folder
4.Every time adding   {
        "id": "FingerprintAuth",
        "file": "../js/FingerprintAuth.js",
        "clobbers": [
            "FingerprintAuth"
        ]
    } in cordova_plugins.js before deploying to device.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will at all work in a Hybrid app.

Note however that according to the plug-in page this plug-in requires Android API level 23, which was added only recently. Please first be sure to upgrade to the latest iFix of MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1